# Flux integral and Gauss in two dimensions.

Tags: calculus

Calculate $\int_{\gamma} \vec v \cdot \vec nds$ from below to above. $\vec v=(x,y)$ and $\gamma= \{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 |0\le x \le 1, y=2-x^7\}$

***First direct calculation:***

Parameterisation: $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb R^2, t \rightarrow(t,2-t^7)$

Derivative of $\gamma \rightarrow (1,-7t^6)$, $\vec n=(-7t^6,1)$

$$\int (t,2-t^7)(-7t^6,1)=2$$

***With Gauss:***

$div(\vec v)=1+1=2$

We close the above curve with a line $(0,2)\rightarrow (1,1)$

$$\int_{\Omega}2d\mu=\int_{\gamma} \vec v \cdot \vec n ds+\int_{\hat \gamma}\vec v \cdot \vec nds$$

Let $\hat \gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R^2, t \rightarrow (t,2-t)$

Derivative of it would be $\hat \gamma (1,-1)$ then $\hat nds= (-1,-1)dt$

So $\int_{\hat \gamma} \vec v \cdot \vec nds=\int_0^1 (t,2-t)(-1,-1)dt=-2$

Rewrite $\Omega: \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 |0\le x \le1, 2-x \le y \le 2-x^7\}$

Then: $$\int_{\Omega}div(\vec v)d\mu=\int_{\gamma} \vec v \cdot \vec nds +\int_{\hat \gamma} \vec v \cdot \vec nds$$

$$\int_{\Omega} 2d\mu=\int_0^1 dx \int_{2-x}^{2-x^7}dy2=\frac{3}{4}$$

We are looking for $\int_{\gamma}\vec v \cdot \vec nds$ but this comes out to be $\frac{11}{4}$

I triple-checked every integral, and every calculation with different online calculators, but the results are not the same, it's driving me crazy...Can someone tell me where went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's correct the "***First direct calculation:***"

Parameterisation: $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb R^2, t \rightarrow(t,2-t^7)$

Derivative of $\gamma \rightarrow (1,-7t^6)$, $\vec n=(7t^6,1)$ **(note the sign change)**

$$\int_0^1 (t,2-t^7)\cdot(7t^6,1)\,dt=\frac{11}4$$

Comment: ehmmm the question asks to calculate it from down to up, shouldn't we change the sign of the derivative so it goes from below to above?

Comment: ou yeah it still is....ok yeah thanks ,,,cant believe it took me more than 1 hour on this.